# How to serialize Vue.js state across multiple components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, serialization

I have a fairly small web-app with a handful of components. I store in the app and in each component a `config` object inside of `data` that contains the user-settable state, like any toggle buttons or drop-downs they can choose. I want to serialize (and later deserialize and set) the current user-selected state, i.e. the `config`s across all my components as well as the top-level `config`. My app is small enough that I can easily write this by hand for the half-dozen components I have, but is there a right way to lay this out?

For example, should a component's `config` be part of the `props` of the component? That way I could have them all be linked to sub-objects in the top-level `config` and serializing/deserialization is trivial. But I hadn't been doing that since the component themselves are responsible for maintaining their `config`; the input forms to set those are part of the component and not external and the config is not necessary. Moreover, any internal change to a component's `config`s would have to be reflected in the global `config`.

I'm not using Vuex for this project.

Comment: If you want to persist a user's config info between sessions, and the info doesn't need to be secure, you may want to look into window.localStorage.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm not worried about persisting the data but about gathering it in the first place. Currently it's spread out between the main app object and all the components, which is where it logically belongs. But now my my serialization needs to dig into each component object to pull out it's contents. Deserialization is similar. I suspect there's a better way to do organize it. I wouldn't have this problem if I didn't use components; I'd put this all in one big 'config' object, but components are convenient for other reasons obviously.

Comment: Not sure why you are not using Vuex, because this is the type of problem that Vuex solves.  It is a central repository.  You could create, store, and retrieve your config object(s) easily from any component.

Comment: That may be. I am not using it because the documentation states that "you'll know when you need it" and that it's not generally worth it for smaller projects.That seemed to fit my project, at least until now. If there's a smart way of doing this without Vuex, I'd prefer that.

Comment: Not knowing how to proceed because you need centralized data is probably what's meant by knowing when you need it.  (You're there now.)  Where did you see it said that it's not worth it for smaller projects?  What problem did you have with your props config tree idea?

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern says that for a simple app, I'll most likely be fine without Vuex. Maybe I'm increasingly non-simple. I only avoided putting props in config because conceptually the config values are local to the component and are not modified by the outside app. Think like a "show more" toggle to show all results inside of component: the rest of the app doesn't particularly care about that so making it props seems wrong to me. If it's in props, any addition inside the component will require a (tiny) change in the overall app.